# OR on INNER JOIN 3 Tables

Tags: mysql

I'm having some problems with this query and i don't know where's the error.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT(A.email) 
FROM TABLE A 
JOIN TABLE B 
    ON A.id=B.userid
JOIN TABLE C 
    ON A.id=C.userid
WHERE C.sfID = 200 
OR B.sfID = 200
```

When I run the query on PHPMyAdmin stays on loading forever.

Edit:

Here are the tables to try to explain

```
TABLE A
USERID | EMAIL

TABLE B 
ID | SID | USERID

TABLE C
ID | SID | USERID

TABLE D (i don't want to use this)
SID | SNAME
```

So, i need to get the email from TABLE A of the users who have SID 200 on TABLE B or TABLE C

Comment: How many rows have each table?

Comment: Add `EXPLAIN` before the query and see what make it so long

Comment: Distinct isn't a function.  use it as `SELECT distinct A.Email`...  the distinct applies to all values in the select, not just those in ()'s.

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED:

I think you're missing join criteria on C which is causing the engine to have to join more records together than it should; or you could join C though B instead of A.  This only works because you're using an INNER Join in all cases.  If they are outer joins, we couldn't go from A->B->C

This may be faster:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.email 
FROM TABLE A 
JOIN TABLE B 
  ON A.id=B.userid
JOIN TABLE C 
  ON A.id=C.userid
 AND B.userID = C.USERID
WHERE (C.sfID = 200 OR B.sfID = 200)
```

A-->B

A-->C

the engine doens't know how to tie B-C so if B and C have multiple records for each value in A, then you're joining a M:M, in effect a cross join.

or it could be written as: thus joining A-->B-->C

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.email 
FROM TABLE A 
JOIN TABLE B 
  ON A.id=B.userid
JOIN TABLE C 
  ON B.userID = C.userID
WHERE (C.sfID = 200 OR B.sfID = 200)
```

Comment: Tanks but i think i don't need to join B with C look to the edit. Or i'm wrong and need to link them too?

Comment: Worked :D I think the problem whas the () on WHERE. Thanks

Comment: the () on the or should have no bearing really, I added it to simply ensure if other criteria is added, the Or's remain tied.

Comment: False alarm. I saw the wrong window. Still loading and don't give results.

Comment: You'll need to add an explain plan at this point.  All I can think of is the PK/FK relationships haven't been defined and/or indexes are missing/corrupt or we're dealing with BILLIONS of records

Comment: Not billions but millions of records. I solved half problem with this 

`SELECT email FROM TABLE A WHERE userid = (SELECT userid FROM TABLE B Where sid = 200 UNION SELECT userid FROM TABLE C Where sid = 200)`

The problem now is the error returns more than 1 row. I have any way to select multiple records from subquery? Subquery is working fine the problem is how can i now select multiple records to convert the id's on emails

Comment: change  `userid =` to `userid in`. = can only have one value.  in can have many.  Though a correlated subqery should be faster (exists)